# Android Application.onCreate long process

Tags: android

I have a long process during application launch. I want show progress dialog during the process.
If my application is restarted, I don't know which activity will be started.

Is there good practice to show progress dialog during restarting of application? I want to prevent any activity initialization until process is finished.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if there is the possibility to show on UI before an activity starts but why don't you define an activity with an asynctask that will comunicate with the process retrieving some data to know wich percentage to show. 
If the asynctask finishes you can start the next activity and finish this one to avoid back stack history, otherwise a restart of the app will restart the same activity because you can define the category launcher on the manifest.

Comment: I have many activities in my application. Process of application can be killed by Android while it is on background (e.g. because of low memory). 
If user backs to application, an attempt to restore last active activity will made. In that case it becomes difficult to use loading activity. Restoring of application is different than first launch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a loading Activity that shows the user a background with a **progress bar** to tell him you're loading stuff. Meanwhile you should load your data in a **separate thread** (using AsyncTask/Loader etc.) and when it finish, you can start whichever Activity you want.

Also, if your data **has** to be loaded, you can also show that activity while you're loading the stuff in a **Service** so it won't be easily killed. However, try to use a basic logic:

1 Your app is opened -> Have you loaded the data?

2a (Yes) start your activity

2b (No) start the service and show the progress

3 The user/system closes your app and reopens it -> back to 1)

Comment: Thanks for advice. I think, it isn't simple solution during restoring of application. See comments in question.

Comment: So that, I should put code in ALL my activities in onCreate method which will check if data is loaded and show progress dialog.

I thought that there is present one entry point to application with UI. Unfortunately, no.

Comment: You can do a generic Activity which checks that and inherit from it in your other activities.

Comment: Yes, I will do so. Thank you very much.